# An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses:

Tags: symfony

i uploaded my project to the server when i configure the databse connection inside the .env file it display to me that error
`An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for wnpilxkx_yassine failed: Name or service not known`
my connection line :

`export DATABASE_URL="mysql://wnpilxkx_yassine:#QXKzJS[AvMP@127.0.0.1:3306/wnpilxkx_easemploy"`

Comment: Could you please try to replace 127.0.0.1 by localhost

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to urlencode your password because Doctrine is failing to parse the DATABASE_URL correctly.

Try:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://wnpilxkx_yassine:%23QXKzJS%5BAvMP@127.0.0.1:3306/wnpilxkx_easemploy"
```

Also make sure that in config/packages/doctrine.yaml you have:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

DO NOT apply the "resolve:" env var processor.